# have a many gallery boxs in one page but only first box work Django

Tags: python, html, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzKcn.jpg)I have js gallery and i use django.I have many gallery boxs in one page but only first box realy work.It's can zoom in, zoom out etc.I think i have js problem but others js works normal. Only gallery boxs doesn't work.
i want do many thik but never work.
1.i add script in forloop
2.i add manualy class
3.i add style

**gallery.html**

```
{% extends 'BaseScreen/based.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    {% for photos in x %}

        {% with a=photos %}
            <main id="js-page-content" role="main" class="page-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div id="panel-1" class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-hdr">
                            <h2>
                                {{ a }} <span class="fw-300"><i>Example</i></span>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="panel-toolbar">
                                <button class="btn btn-panel" data-action="panel-collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" data-offset="0,10" data-original-title="Collapse"></button>
                                <button class="btn btn-panel" data-action="panel-fullscreen" data-toggle="tooltip" data-offset="0,10" data-original-title="Fullscreen"></button>
                                <button class="btn btn-panel" data-action="panel-close" data-toggle="tooltip" data-offset="0,10" data-original-title="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-container show">
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                <div id="js-lightgallery">
                                    {% for photo in post %}
                                        {% if photo.ders == a %}
                                            {% if photo.img %}
                                                <a class="jg-entry entry-visible" href="{{photo.img.url}}" data-sub-html="{{photos.title}}">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ photo.img.url }}" alt="{{photo.title}}">
                                                </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </main>
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock  %}
```

**based.html**

```
{% load static %}
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            Light Gallery - Miscellaneous - SmartAdmin v4.0.2
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="Light Gallery">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
        <!-- Call App Mode on ios devices -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <!-- Remove Tap Highlight on Windows Phone IE -->
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <!-- base css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="{% static 'css/vendors.bundle.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="{% static 'css/app.bundle.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="{% static 'css/miscellaneous/lightgallery/lightgallery.bundle.css' %}">
        {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'img/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'img/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg' %}" color="#5bbad5">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="{% static 'css/miscellaneous/lightgallery/lightgallery.bundle.css' %}">

    </head>
    <body class="mod-bg-1 nav-function-top" >
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page-inner">
                {% include 'BaseStyle/SideBar.html' %}
                <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                    {% include 'BaseStyle/Header.html' %}
                    <main id="js-page-content" role="main" class="page-content">
                        {% block body %}

                        {% endblock %}
                    </main>
                    <div class="page-content-overlay" data-action="toggle" data-class="mobile-nav-on"></div>
                    <footer class="page-footer" role="contentinfo">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-1 text-muted">
                            <span class="hidden-md-down fw-700">2019 © SmartAdmin by&nbsp;<a href='https://www.gotbootstrap.com' class='text-primary fw-500' title='gotbootstrap.com' target='_blank'>gotbootstrap.com</a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul class="list-table m-0">
                                <li><a href="intel_introduction.html" class="text-secondary fw-700">About</a></li>
                                <li class="pl-3"><a href="info_app_licensing.html" class="text-secondary fw-700">License</a></li>
                                <li class="pl-3"><a href="info_app_docs.html" class="text-secondary fw-700">Documentation</a></li>
                                <li class="pl-3 fs-xl"><a href="https://wrapbootstrap.com/user/MyOrange" class="text-secondary" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="{% static 'js/vendors.bundle.js '%}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/app.bundle.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/miscellaneous/lightgallery/lightgallery.bundle.js' %}"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var $initScope = $('#js-lightgallery');
                if ($initScope.length)
                {
                    $initScope.justifiedGallery(
                    {
                        border: -1,
                        rowHeight: 150,
                        margins: 8,
                        waitThumbnailsLoad: true,
                        randomize: false,
                    }).on('jg.complete', function()
                    {
                        $initScope.lightGallery(
                        {
                            thumbnail: true,
                            animateThumb: true,
                            showThumbByDefault: true,
                        });
                    });
                };
                $initScope.on('onAfterOpen.lg', function(event)
                {
                    $('body').addClass("overflow-hidden");
                });
                $initScope.on('onCloseAfter.lg', function(event)
                {
                    $('body').removeClass("overflow-hidden");
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
```

**script**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var $initScope = $('#js-lightgallery');
                if ($initScope.length)
                {
                    $initScope.justifiedGallery(
                    {
                        border: -1,
                        rowHeight: 150,
                        margins: 8,
                        waitThumbnailsLoad: true,
                        randomize: false,
                    }).on('jg.complete', function()
                    {
                        $initScope.lightGallery(
                        {
                            thumbnail: true,
                            animateThumb: true,
                            showThumbByDefault: true,
                        });
                    });
                };
                $initScope.on('onAfterOpen.lg', function(event)
                {
                    $('body').addClass("overflow-hidden");
                });
                $initScope.on('onCloseAfter.lg', function(event)
                {
                    $('body').removeClass("overflow-hidden");
                });
            });[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b7AX.jpg
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - How does it not work, and how is it suppose to work? Please add in those details. Also, you mention and tagged Javascript, but there is no Javascript in your example

Comment: I have a gallery with js codes in it. It can download zoom in, zoom out etc.When open page first box can do it bur another box doesn't

Comment: Sorry for that.I don't think the problem is js

Comment: you didnt end one of the foorloop.

Comment: i add close end forloop but, dont change any think

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamic id can solve problems